# rsibreak or xfce4-time-out-plugin like software?

Tags: gnome, hibernate, xfce

I wanted a software just like RsiBreak for KDE4 or xfce4-time-out-plugin for XFCE4 desktop env , however , xfce4-time-out-plugin doesn't have a command line interface , which is needed when system `hibernate` and `resume`.

I wanted some program that best fit in for XFCE desktop , or i'll have to hack the source code of `xfce4-time-out-plugin` myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workrave, http://www.workrave.org/